# Salesforce example Apex code throws error

Tags: apex

The following example Apex code is throwing an error. Being new to Apex, how is this best rectified? It seems the error wants the Class to close rather than expecting more code.

[Original source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_admin_guide.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_admin_force_rbl.htm)

Thanks.

```
public class Test {
    // Create your list of IDs
    List<Id> rollupsToRun = new List<Id>();
    List<FinServ__RollupByLookupConfig__c> queriedRollups = [SELECT Id FROM FinServ__RollupByLookupConfig__c WHERE FinServ__Active__c = true];

    for (FinServ__RollupByLookupConfig__c rollup : queriedRollups) {
        rollupsToRun.add(rollup.Id);
    }

    // Create an instance of RollupRecalculationBatchable
    FinServ.RollupRecalculationBatchable job = new FinServ.RollupRecalculationBatchable(rollupsToRun);

    // Run the rollups
    Database.executeBatch(job);
}
```

Error:

> Line 6: Expecting '}' but was: 'for'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class is missing a **method** which should contain the code snippet that you have in here. As in current form, your Apex is not syntactically correct and thus you are getting a compile time error here.

The example only mentions a code snippet and not the complete class. Put in a simple way, you are limited to what you can write in a class directly (e.g., variable declarations, methods, etc.) but the actual "execution logic" is always written in methods.

Your class should look like as below:

```
public class Test {
    private void doSomething() {
        ... the code from the example ....
    } // method closes here
} // class closes here
```

Take a look on the documentation and trailhead to get started on Apex. Below are some good places to get started on Apex:

- [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm)
- [What is Apex?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_what_is_apex.htm)
- [Apex Basics and Database Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database)

Comment: ...I need more sleep.